# Função em javascript sempre retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Sei que existem várias perguntas parecidas, mas nenhuma das soluções apresentadas funcionaram :(

Tenho esta função que recebe dados por parâmetro:

```
function funcao(valor) {
    var a;
    $.getJSON(/* aqui retorno de uma WebService*/, function (dados) {
        if ("error" in dados) {
            a = 0; //seria o true e false, mas não funcionaram também
            return a;
        } else {
            /* se o WS está ok faz algo e então seria true */
            a = 1;
            return a;
        }
    });
}
```

já tentei tratar o return com

```
return true;
return 1;
return "true";
return 'true';
return a.val();
return a.value;
return a;
return !!a;
```

esta por sua vez é usada da seguinte maneira:

```
function valida(){
    if(funcao(dados)){
        faz algo
    } else if(funcao(dados)){
        algo
    }else{
        algo
    }
}
```

já tentei tratar o if com

```
if(func(dados)){}
if(func(dados) == true){}
if(func(dados) === true){}
if(func(dados) == 1){}
if(func(dados) === 1){}
if(func(dados) === "1"){} //a parte de == ou === tentei também e vale para os demais
if(func(dados) === "true"){}
if(func(dados) === 'true'){}
if(func(dados).val()){}
if(func(dados).value){}
if(func(dados).value === true){}
if(func(dados).val() === true){}
```

todas essas tentativas retornaram valor **undefined**

Já li muitas perguntas daqui do próprio stack e de outros lugares, mas todas as possibilidades de solução não funcionaram.

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: A função `funcao(dados) {}` que está retornando "undefined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não funciona desta forma porque o Ajax é *assíncrono*, ou seja, quando você chama a função que por sua vez chama a outra função esperando receber um valor do Ajax, ele imediatamente retorna *undefined* porque o retorno do Ajax não é imediato.

O que você pode fazer é usar `.then` que processa o código após o retorno do Ajax. Também é preciso passar um parâmetro na função `valida(dados)`, onde `dados` é o valor que será enviado à função `funcao(valor)`.

Veja como ficaria:

```
function valida(dados){

   funcao(dados).then(function(retorno){
      if(retorno){
         faz algo
      } else if(!retorno){
         faz algo
      }else{
         faz algo
      }
   });

}

function funcao(valor) {
    return $.getJSON(/* aqui retorno de uma WebService*/).then(function (dados) {
        if ("error" in dados) {
            return false;
        } else {
            /* se o WS está ok faz algo e então seria true */
            return true;
        }

    });
}

valida("algum valor"); // aqui chama a função
```

Comment: Então o .then é utilizado após a função que devo "esperar", ele faz eu trabalhar de maneira síncrona, nos lugares que eu declaro.
Ali no getJSON() você colocou o .then após o get, isso faz diferença?
pq após o .then os dados quem teriam na variável "dados" não seria o retorno dele e não o retorno do JSON (como esperado)?

Comment: A variavel "dados" no get é o json que virá como retorno no ajax.

Comment: Se houver alguma chave "error", irá retornar "false"

Comment: O "then" apos o get eh o callback, senao o codigo nao espera o retorno.